# Using Filter Pipe In Angular 4

Tags: angular, filter, angular2-services, angular-pipe

I'm using a filter pipe in my angular 4 application. But I have a problem since i'm filtering inside an array but also inside of that array. So i can't find that specific name... since i can only find the first array but not the inner array. Here's my JSON response and my pipe code below. Here i can only search the `"admin name and email"` BUT i can't search the `"Outlet name, address AND Role name"`

> JSON

```
{
  "token": "eyefqffiwqnrfoqif",
  "users": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Admin",
      "email": "admin@yahoo.com",
      "created_at": "2018-01-05 07:17:41",
      "updated_at": "2018-01-05 09:17:41",
      "outlet": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Sarawak Energy Berhad",
      "address": "Kuching City",
      "contact_number": "1300-88-3111",
      "created_at": "2018-01-05 10:17:44",
      "updated_at": "2018-01-05 10:17:44"
    },
      "roles": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Admin",
          "created_at": "2018-01-05 10:17:40",
          "updated_at": "2018-01-05 10:17:40",
          "pivot": {
            "model_id": 1,
            "role_id": 1
          },
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

> FILTER PIPE

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'search'
})
export class SearchPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: any, term: any): any {
    if (term === undefined) return items;

    return items.filter(function(item) {
      for(let property in item){
        if (item[property] === null){
          continue;
        }
        if(item[property].toString().toLowerCase().includes(term.toLowerCase())){
          return true;
        }
      }
      return false;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: your JSON does not have that value

Comment: @Sajeetharan. Help please :)

Comment: post your complete JSON

Comment: @Sajeetharan. This is my complete JSON. I can search ONLY admin name and email BUT not outet name, description AND role name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case your outlet is another object inside your each array object, so you need to specifically add a filter for the outlet as follows,

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filter'
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
 transform(items: any, term: any): any {
    if (term === undefined) return items;

    return items.filter(function(item) {
      for(let property in item){

        if (item[property] === null){
          continue;
        }
        if(item[property].toString().toLowerCase().includes(term.toLowerCase())){
          return true;
        }
         if(property ='outlet'){
           if(item[property].name.toString().toLowerCase().includes(term.toLowerCase())){
           console.log(item[property].name);
          return true;
         }

        }
         if(property ='roles'){
         if (item[property].filter(e => e.name === term.toLowerCase()).length > 0) {
          return true;
         }

        }
       }
      return false;
    });
  }

}
```

**[DEMO STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pipe-example?file=app%2FfilterPipe.ts)**

Comment: Thanks It works on the outlet name, how about the role name?

Comment: you need to add another filter for roles check the updated demo

Comment: There's an error in the role name. Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Comment: where? i dont see

Comment: check the demo attached.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pipe-example-kaz7wq?file=app/app.component.ts. Check this out. Type admin in search bar and it can't find it

Comment: sure ! did just now